# Showing failed to compile error when deploying nextjs app on vercel on this path ./app/page.js

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

When i try to deploy my nextjs app on vercel that showing an error - **failed to compile**. and there are two more errors.

> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1.

> BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1.

How to solve this error?

[image]

Just connect vercel to my github repo and clicked on deploy button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanx, now this issue has been resolved